# How Can I Get PowerMock to Return the Expected Value from a Static Method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Consider the following field and method from a class i need to test.

```
private final static String pathToUUID = "path/to/my/file.txt";

public String getUuid () throws Exception {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathToUUID)));;
}
```

The UUID is stored in a file that is created on the application's first run. A `file.txt` exists in the location indicated by `pathToUUID`. I am trying (and struggling) to write a unit test for this method.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Files.class})
public class MyTest {

    private final String expected = "19dcd640-0da7-4b1a-9048-1575ee9c5e39";

    @Test
    public void testGetUuid() throws Exception {
        UUIDGetter getter = new UUIDGetter();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
         when(Files.readAllBytes(any(Path.class)).thenReturn(expected.getBytes());
        String retrieved = getter.getUuid();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedUUID, retrieved);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `when().thenReturn()` is not called during testing and the test performs as an integration test, reading the file from the file system and returning its value, rather simply than the mock value i expect.  However, if i spoof a call to `Files.readAllBytes()` in the test method and echo the result to the console, the `expected` value displays.

So, how can i get my method under test to properly function with the PowerMock `when()-thenReturn()` pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing a similar problem, i solved this by making the following changes to my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({UUIDStasher.class})
public class TestUUIDStasher {

    private final String expectedUUID = "19dcd640-0da7-4b1a-9048-1575ee9c5e39";
    Path spoofPath = Paths.get("C:\\DIRECTORY");

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Paths.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
        when(Paths.get(any(String.class))).thenReturn(spoofPath);
        when(Files.readAllBytes(any(Path.class))).thenReturn(expectedUUID.getBytes());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUUID() throws Exception {
        UUIDStasher stasher = new UUIDStasher();
        String retrieved = stasher.getUuid();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedUUID, retrieved);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class that you need to test is written in a bad way. The path shouldn't be hard coded - make it parametrizable - for example inject the path via the constructor. Then, in your integration tests just inject the path to your test resources and you're ready to go. No PowerMock, no hacks - simple constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

JDK classes are hard to deal with when using PowerMock. Here's what I would do in your case:

Refactor `UUIDGetter` to add a constructor for testing purposes that accepts the path to the "uuid" file:

```
package so37059406;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class UUIDGetter {

    private final static String PATH_TO_UUID = "path/to/my/file.txt";

    private final String path;

    public UUIDGetter() {
        this(PATH_TO_UUID);
    }

    // for testing purposes
    protected UUIDGetter(final String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getUuid() throws Exception {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(this.path)));
    }
}
```

then test it like this:

```
package so37059406;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UUIDGetterTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetUuid() throws Exception {
        final UUIDGetter getter = new UUIDGetter(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("so37059406/uuid.txt").getPath());
        assertEquals("19dcd640-0da7-4b1a-9048-1575ee9c5e39", getter.getUuid());
    }
}
```

With a resource file (in test resources folder) named "so37059406/uuid.txt" and containing (no end-of-line):

```
19dcd640-0da7-4b1a-9048-1575ee9c5e39
```

---

This is IMHO, way better, because:

- No powermock: it's a powerful tool but it comes with a price (slower tests, possible tests strange interactions
- It's more readable / easy to understand